# Separating podcast mp3 files from music files?

Tags: iphone, podcasts

I have some mp3 files on the computer of podcasts I want to hear. I can simply sync them to the iPhone (4, iOs 5.x) like any other music file but I wondered if there's a way to treat them differently - I don't want them to appear in my music (for example, when shuffling songs I don't want the podcasts to appear).

Is there a way to separate music from podcasts? In iTunes I see a "podcasts" tab in my iPhone but I don't see how to import files there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the tracks to iTunes as usual, then right click on the track and select "Get info". There will be a tab named "Options" in the window that shows up, click on that and you will see an option named "Media kind". If you set the media kind to "Podcast" the file will show up in the Podcast section of iTunes and your iPhone.